# Old value and new value of record after update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create stored procedure which will find out old value and new value of updated record.
It should include Dynamic query for finding column name at run time.

I am using oracle 12C for this.

```
create table student (    
    id number(6) primary key,
    name varchar2(50),
    city varchar2(50),
    address varchar2(100),
    createdDateTime date,
    updatedDatetime date
);

insert into student values(1,'abc1','abc1','abc1','09-Jan-20','12-Jan-20');
insert into student values(2,'pqr','pqr','pqr','09-Jan-20',null);
```

student table-

```
ID      Name    City     Address    Create_time UpdatedTime
1       abc1    abc1     abc1       09-Jan-20   12-Jan-20
2       pqr     pqr      pqr        09-Jan-20   null

create table studentHistory (
    id number(6) ,
    name varchar2(50),
    city varchar2(50),
    address varchar2(100),
    DatetimeCreated date
);

insert into StudentHistory values(1,null,'abc',null,'10-Jan-20');
insert into StudentHistory values(1,'abc',null,null,'11-Jan-20');
insert into StudentHistory values(1,null,null,'abc','12-Jan-20');
```

Student history table-

```
ID  Name    City        Address DatetimeCreated
1   null    abc          null     10-Jan-20
1   abc     null         null     11-Jan-20
1   null    null         abc      12-Jan-20
```

Required output-->

```
Id  ColumnName Old Value New Value Updatetime
1   City        abc         abc1    '10-01-20'
1   name        abc         abc1    '11-01-20'
1   City        abc         abc1    '12-01-20'
```

Comment: "I need to create stored procedure ..." - no, you need to create a trigger, they are used for such purposes. There are *zillion* of examples in the internet, do some search, write some code. Come back if you can't make it work - if so, edit your question and post code you wrote and errors you got.

Comment: You should add the old values of an update to the history table. Right now there's no chance to get the old values for an `UPDATE` unless it's the very last one. And then you just need a `SELECT` to get the old values.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stickybit. Populating your history table is really the starting point. You should create a trigger as mentioned by @Littlefoot to update/insert in your history table, maybe using merge https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

But I tried something just based on the data you provided, don't think this is what you're looking for but still posting it here as it may help someone else in the future:

```
with name_cte
as
(
select 
a.id,
a.name as new_value,
b.name as old_value,
b.datetimecreated,
'name' as column_name
from student a
join studenthistory b
on a.id=b.id
and b.name is not null
)
,city_cte
as
(
select 
a.id,
a.city as new_value,
b.city as old_value,
b.datetimecreated,
'city' as column_name
from student a
join studenthistory b
on a.id=b.id
and b.city is not null
)
,address_cte
as
(
select 
a.id,
a.address as new_value,
b.address as old_value,
b.datetimecreated,
'address' as column_name
from student a
join studenthistory b
on a.id=b.id
and b.address is not null
)
select 
a.id,
a.column_name,
a.old_value,
a.new_value,
a.datetimecreated as updatetime
from name_cte a
union all
select
b.id,
b.column_name,
b.old_value,
b.new_value,
b.datetimecreated as updatetime
from city_cte b
union all
select
c.id,
c.column_name,
c.old_value,
c.new_value,
c.datetimecreated as updatetime
from address_cte c
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63c33caae4cb561866229e157f88b959)